# Designing hash function in space-efficient identity based encryption

Tags: hash

Let $n$ be an RSA-prime and we know prime factorization of $n(=pq)$.

The hash function is the current context maps from a given user identity(id) to a positive integer less than $n$, whose jacobi symbol value is equal to 1.

Assume $id$ is any positive integer i.e., $id\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

$H : id -> J(n)$

where $J(n)=\{x| x<n , (\frac{x}{n})=+1\}$

Method i am following :

```
i=0;
while(1) {
    MulMod(R,id+i,1,n);                      //R=(id+i)%n
    if((Jacobi(R,p)==1 && Jacobi(R,q)==1)||(Jacobi(R,p)== -1 && Jacobi(R,q)==-1)) break;
    else i++;
}
```

explanation :

1.$i=0$;

1.$temp=(id+i)\%n$.

2.if $temp \in J(n)$ output $temp$ else increment $i$ and continue .

Idea behind this is hash function is mapping to a value nearer to $id\%n$  whose Jacobi value is $+1$ in positive direction(increment of $id$) .

Is my method good enough ? or please provide any other good hash function  .

Comment: The obvious (and more efficient) way to come up with a value with a Jacobi of 1 would be to use a hash function to create a value between 1 and $n-1$ (relatively prime to $n$), and then square it (modulo $n$).

Comment: @poncho That relative prime is nearer to id ? or any random one ?

Comment: @poncho : $\:$ It would probably be important that the sampling of values $\hspace{2 in}$ with a Jacobi symbol of 1 be oblivious. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: well, given that the QR decisional problem is hard if you don't know the factorization, I suspect it might not matter if my method would generate only QR values (because someone else would not be able to distinguish anyways).  Of course, that would depend a great deal on why you want values with Jacobi 1 in the first place.

Comment: @hanu: I had assumed that you would generate a random looking value; one way would be to feed the id into a random number generator, generate $\log N + 64$ bits, and then take the result modulo $N$.  However, as long as you generate values significantly larger than $\sqrt{N}$, it probably doesn't matter a great deal how you do it (as the squaring process is one-way if you don't know the factorization)